# Raster appears smooth when created but pixelated when opened again

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, topography, bathymetry

I have a set of xyz points that I want to turn into a raster format for bathymetry.  I am using the Topo to Raster (3D analyst) tool and using the depth as the Field and PointElevation as they Type.  When the tool finishes it outputs a very smooth looking raster.  However when I open a new ArcMap document and pull in the created raster it looks very pixelated.  I can't figure out what is causing the change.  One thing I did notice is that at the bottom of the original Arcmap window the units are listed in Decimal Degrees while in the new Arcmap the units are listed as meters.[image: Smooth original]
[image: pixelated new]

Can anyone explain to me what is happening when I am opening the raster in a new ArcMap window?  How can a switch the dataframe between meters and decimal degrees and will this change fix the pixelation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArcGIS has a [raster layer display resampling feature](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/improving-the-display-of-raster-data.htm). Assuming the spatial resolution is the same for the input and output raster data, the 3D Analyst output likely has either Bilinear Interpolation or Cubic Convolution resampling applied to produce a smooth looking raster on-screen. You can apply the resampling (or check if the resampling is applied) in the Layer Properties:

> right-click raster layer > Layer Properties > Display > Resample during
>   display using:

Note that as soon as you close the raster layer, the display resampling option will be lost unless you save the map as a .mxd document.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.  The layer does have Bilinear Interpolation selected.